# How to return parent object by filtering nested property

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter an array with nested objects, but the parent isn't being returned when filtering on a child property.

```
let line = "xyz";

let data = [
    {
        "header": {
            "po_no": "P.O. Number"
        },
        "line": line
    },
    {
        "header": {
            "po_no": "Another P.O. Number"
        },
        "line": line
    }
];
```

...

```
data.filter(item => { 
  return item.header.po_no === 'P.O. Number' // Evaluates to true
})
```

I'd like to return the entire `item` when its `header.po_no` matches a string.

I'm not sure how to debug this since it's not returning any values when the return condition evaluates to true.

Expected output:

```
[{
  "header": {
    "po_no": "P.O. Number"
  },
  "line": line
}]
```

How can I return the entire array index when a sub-property is matching using a filter?

Comment: Your code looks fine

Comment: "po_no': "Another P.O. Number" this line is incorrect. " Not closed after po_no

Comment: Ah, I am missing a return in my actual code... Thanks guys!!!

Comment: No, like @AdityaBhave said, you have a type: `"po_no'` should be `"po_no"`

Comment: You can return implicitly from arrow functions.`data.filter(item => item.header.po_no === 'P.O. Number'
)`

Comment: Yes, I was forgetting to `return data...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter` returns a *new* Array; it doesn't modify the array. So if you're expecting `data` to have that output, it won't. However, this will:

```
const expectedItems = data.filter(item => { 
  return item.header.po_no === 'P.O. Number' // Evaluates to true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had ' quote type in your code.
filtered data saved to variable.

```
let line = "xyz";

let data = [
  {
    "header": {
    "po_no": "P.O. Number"
    },
    "line": line
  }, 
  {
    "header": {
    "po_no": "Another P.O. Number"
  },
  "line": line
  }
];

const filtered = data.filter(item => { 
  return item.header.po_no === 'P.O. Number' // Evaluates to true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with arrow function would solve this in the most concise way. `filter` returns the main array and the filtered items where `find` would only return the specific item that matched.

```js
let line = "xyz";

let data = [{
    "header": { "po_no": "P.O. Number" },
    line
  },
  {
    "header": { "po_no": "Another P.O. Number" },
    line
  }
];

let filter = data.filter(d => d.header.po_no === 'P.O. Number') // return arr
let find = data.find(d => d.header.po_no === 'P.O. Number') // return just the item

console.log(filter)
console.log(find)
```

When dealing with arrow functions and you have a direct return you do not need to open a function bracket ... just do:

```
data.filter(d => d.header.po_no === 'P.O. Number')  // <-- no { return ... }
```

Also note that since your property is called `line` you can simply define your object as:

```
  {
    "header": { "po_no": "Another P.O. Number" },
    line  // <-- same prop name as your variable name
  }
```